# How to bulk-convert horizontally-oriented Japanese text to vertically oriented?

Tags: discussion, resources

I would like to bulk-convert a largish amount of horizontally-oriented Japanese text to vertically oriented.

I tried using this online converter

https://www.izuna.sylphid.jp/izuna_web.html

...but I can't figure out how to save/download the generated PDF.  Is it possible?  (Or is this just a free demo, so that, in order to be able to save/download the generated PDF, one first needs to pay for/buy something?)

I also tried this converter: http://hinata.la.coocan.jp/tool/tategaki.cgi , but it does not perform any column wrapping (so one ends up with columns of text that can be several screenfuls tall), and there is no simple way to save a PDF of the results.

Does anyone know of another way to perform this horizontal-to-vertical conversion in bulk?

Comment: I think MS Word has features for this.

Comment: BTW, on small text that I tried, your first link worked just fine. When I click the left button, it opens as a PDF document on my browser, that I can save (well, actually it's already saved in Downloads), print or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is the current format of the Japanese text. If you have it in plain text or html and you are ready to manually tweak html, then all you need to do is add `"writing-mode: vertical-rl;"`
to your html document's style property, then open it in a browser and print to PDF.

You can see a more elaborate explanation here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652227/making-vertical-japanese-text